# how to put markup around indiviual radio buttons

Tags: forms

Is it possible to set the markup (#prefix and #suffix) around individual radio buttons? I know that I can add these fields to the radio button group, but that would mean that I would be wrapping the entire group, which is not what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Forms API matrix you can.  See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#radio  Have you tried some code to see if it does what you are looking for?

You can set '#options' for the radios to be a variable:

```
$rads = array( 
  0 => '<span>' . t('Yes') . '</span>', 
  1 => '<span>' . t('No') . '</span>', );

$form['fldset8']['exp_radios'] = array(
 '#type' => 'radios', 
 '#options' => $rads, );
```

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. But I don't really know how to test it. Where would I put the tag? I have my options listed as '#options'=> array(1,2,3) -- so, where would I put a #prefix element?

Comment: You can set '#options' for the radios to be a variable:


$rads = array(
0 => '<span>' . t('Yes') . '</span>',
1 => '<span>' . t('No') . '</span>',
);

$form['fldset8']['exp_radios'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#options' => $rads,
);